# Convertir imagen XPM en PNG mediante PHP o JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php

Estoy creando una aplicación web en PHP y JavaScript/JQuery para extraer imágenes almacenadas como texto en formato XPM en una base de datos PostgreSQL.

El programa actualmente consigue obtener y generar correctamente el archivo XPM a partir del texto en la base de datos. Se puede ver, modificar o incluso convertir dicho archivo con XnViewMP o distintos conversores en línea.

Lo que yo quiero es poder convertir la imagen automáticamente. Es decir, obtener la cadena, generar el archivo XPM y acto seguido convertir dicho archivo en PNG sin tener que utilizar programas externos o conversores en línea.

La cuestión es que he probado todo lo que he encontrado:

- He probado con las bibliotecas ImageGD e ImageGD2 de PHP, con ImageGD dice que el archivo XPM no es válido y la librería ImageGD2 no llega ni a funcionar, al menos en XAMPP.
- He probado a crear un canvas en JavaScript, insertar la foto y guardar el canvas como PNG.
- He probado con APIs de conversores en línea y están muy limitadas.

Aquí os dejo el código con el que genero el archivo XPM/PNG en PHP:

```
foreach ($imagenes as $img) {
        $archivo = fopen($directorio . $img['refimgorig'] . ".xpm", "w") or die("Error al generar archivo!");

        fwrite($archivo, $img['imagen']);
        fclose($archivo);
        array_push($arrayImgs, $directorio . $img['refimgorig'] . ".xpm");

        // Estas dos últimas líneas dependen de ImageGD y no funcionan
        // $xpm = imagecreatefromxpm($directorio . $img['refimgorig'] . ".xpm");
        // imagepng($xpm, $directorio . "test.png");
    }
```

Y por aquí os dejo una de las cadenas completas de una imagen XPM tal cual está almacenada en la base de datos:

- [Imagen en JustPaste.it](https://justpaste.it/bt68h)

---

**ACTUALIZACIÓN 1:**

Añado un enlace al archivo generado:

- [Imagen en formato XPM](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1euZF5hlYyQtpOoWM3xNuFo3ubRXIxqIZ/view?usp=sharing)

Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir la imagen en un servicio que te permita bajar el archivo de texto o binario tal cual sin necesidad de copiar/pegar (como mega, onedrive, gdrive, etc)? Quizá al copiar/pegar en esa página (justpaste.it) estás eliminando el problema del archivo original. Nota: como guardas en un directorio la imagen, obtenla de allí.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Acabo de añadir la foto generada a partir del código. Son varias las imágenes a convertir, pero como mínimo esta da fallo con la librería ImageGD de PHP.

Comment: He comprobado que el soporte de XPM en GD es muy pobre, te voy a recomendar una manera alternativa de resolver tu problema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

He tratado de reproducir tu problema con tu imagen de entrada y he comprobado que con la extensión GD la función de guardado en PNG no funciona correctamente porque al abrirla con [`imagecreatefromxpm()`](https://php.net/readImageBlob) trata la imagen como una imagen con paleta de colores.

Esa afirmación es cierta, aunque sea una paleta de 1284 colores diferentes, pero GD está limitado a una paleta de 256 colores (8 bits), por lo que da como resultado la siguiente imagen PNG:

[image: Imagen generada por createpng]

Sin embargo he probado con la extensión [Imagick](https://php.net/intro.imagick) y el resultado ha sido el esperado:

```
$imagick = new Imagick();
foreach ($imagenes as $img) {
    $imagick->readImageBlob($img['imagen']);
    $imagick->setImageFormat("png");
    $imagick->writeImage($directorio . $img['refimgorig'] . ".png");
}
```

Muestro el resultado en la siguiente imagen PNG:

[image: Imagen generada por Imagick]

Nota: como puedes ver no es necesario que guardes previamente el archivo en disco, puedes trabajar con él directamente desde el campo obtenido de la base de datos.

Comment: ¡MUCHAS GRACIAS! Probaré a incluír Imagick en XAMPP o en el servidor a ver si funciona

Comment: ¿Qué tal te fue con Imagick con XAMPP? No va preinstalado con XAMPP, por lo que requiere de instalación adicional (la instalación de esta extensión en Linux es mucho más sencilla). Si necesitas ayuda con eso házmelo saber o crea una nueva pregunta para que se resuelva allí (es mejor no mezclar temas en una pregunta).

Comment: PD: Si la respuesta te ayudó a resolver el problema no olvides marcarla como correcta, y si queda algo más que necesites o que se haya quedado sin responder házmelo saber para mejorar la respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda. Instalé Imagick sin problemas, solo que con tu solución me daba un error y tuve que modificar un poco el código, quedando de la siguiente manera:            `$imagick = new Imagick();

        foreach ($imagenes as $img) {
            $imagick->readImageBlob($img['imagen']);
            $imagick->setImageFormat("png");
            $imagick->writeImageFile (fopen($directorio . $img['refimgorig'] . ".png", "wb"));
        }`

Comment: Con `$imagick->writeImage()` no necesitas hacer un `fopen()` que, por cierto, no cierras el archivo. Quizá lo que te faltaba era simplemente el `$imagick->setImageFormat("png");`. Agrego esas modificaciones al código de mi respuesta.